# How do I do number formatting using zend form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

Hii...

I want to display decimal before last two digits of a number in zend_form, how can I do that? please suggest. Thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use number_format($value, 2)

or

```
echo substr($value, 0, strlen($value) - 2) , '.' , substr($value, -2);
```

Comment: I do not want to get comma in between the numbers...I got this way - 500,000.00 and I am expecting this way - 500000.00

Comment: This is a bit dirty but I came up with this in 2 minutes... see edit

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Zend_Locale_Format](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.locale.parsing.html) to format numbers. In addition to standard formating (.e.g precission) you can form number according to your locale (.e.g. en, pl, de, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

As Marcin says, the best is to use Zend_Locale_Format as in documentation here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/fr/zend.locale.parsing.html

```
Zend_Locale_Format::getNumber($value);
```

Do not use directly number_format.